# Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

I am using java websoket client to create a websocket connnect in java 8, this is my code:

```
import com.sportswin.soa.robot.common.SessionUtil;
import com.sportswin.soa.robot.model.entity.Robot;
import com.sportswin.soa.robot.model.enumn.RobotStatus;
import com.sportswin.soa.robot.service.impl.RobotService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.URI;

/**
 * @author dolphin
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
public class WebsocketClientConnector {

    @Value("${com.dabai.robot.ws-url}")
    private String websocketUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RobotService robotService;

    public WebsocketClientEndpoint robotNewConnect(Long roomTypeId, String token, String userMark) {
        WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = null;
        String websocketConnUrl = websocketUrl + "?token=" + token + "&roomTypeId=" + roomTypeId + "&robotFlag=1";
        try {
            String appMark = SessionUtil.getThreadLocal("appMark");
            clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI(websocketConnUrl));
            clientEndPoint.userSession.getUserProperties().put("userIdentity", userMark + "-" + appMark + "-" + roomTypeId);
            clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(message -> {
                log.info("addMessageHandler:", message);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Websocket", e);
        }
        return clientEndPoint;
    }
}
```

recently this code throws  `Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` makes  me confusing. this is the full error stack output:

```
2020-08-12 19:56:39.186 ERROR 1 --- [ool-10-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
  at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.<init>(WsFrameBase.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.<init>(WsFrameClient.java:43) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:503) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.websocket.client.WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:53) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.websocket.client.WebsocketClientConnector.robotNewConnect(WebsocketClientConnector.java:46) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.createWebsocketConnection(PlayEntryOperate.java:408) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.createWebsocketHandle(PlayEntryOperate.java:387) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.allowRobotSelfPlay(PlayEntryOperate.java:262) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.lambda$matchByRoomType$2(PlayEntryOperate.java:195) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate$$Lambda$923/1467190450.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.matchByRoomType(PlayEntryOperate.java:181) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.allRoomRobotBalance(PlayEntryOperate.java:170) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.PlayEntryOperate.playRoomEntry(PlayEntryOperate.java:82) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.EnvelopRobotJobHandler.matchTenant(EnvelopRobotJobHandler.java:62) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.EnvelopRobotJobHandler.jobExecutor(EnvelopRobotJobHandler.java:48) ~[classes!/:na]
  at com.sportswin.soa.robot.jobhandler.robot.envelop.EnvelopRobotJobHandler.runJob(EnvelopRobotJobHandler.java:40) ~[classes!/:na]
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor395.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
  at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
```

I am searching from internet but seems no one encount this error. what should I do to fix? by the way, this is the startup script I am using:

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512M -Xms128M \
                -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5009 \
                -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/dump \
                -javaagent:/opt/skywalking/agent/skywalking-agent.jar \
                -Dskywalking.agent.service_name=soa-robot-service \
                -Dskywalking.collector.backend_service=oap:11800 \
                -jar /root/soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Java with the command-line option `-Xmx` , which sets the maximum size of the heap.

[See here for details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard)

Comment: OP already does use -Xmx... albeit with 512M, which seems... ambitious for a Spring app.

Comment: Your suggestion works.  The reason is the memory is too small for so much thread.@Taschi